python -V and pyenv versions show different python version
I got recommended to use pyenv to manage and install python versions.
Until now I've installed python using sudo apt-get install python3.
pyenv recommends using homebrew so I've installed it.
But, because I am using ZSH I need to add every little thing to the glorious PATH.
python -V returns 3.10.12
python3 -V returns 3.10.12
pyenv versions returns system * 3.11.8 (set by /home/george/.pyenv/version)
I am not even sure if this is okay.  I would like to have one global python version, though.
I've install homebrew with :
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Because homebrew wasn't in the zsh's path I did:
 9959  test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval "$(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
 9960  test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
 9961  echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.zshrc

Next I've installed pyenv:
 9963  brew update\n
 9964  V
 9965  brew install pyenv

Next, I've added pyenv to zsh path:
 9967  echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
 9968  echo '[[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
 9969  echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
 9970  exec "$SHELL"

I've then installed Python 3.11
 9971  pyenv -V
 9972  pyenv install 3.11
 9973  echo $VIRTUAL_ENV\n
 9974  pyenv global 3.11

And from here I've noticed that pythong -V and pyenv versions are different:
 9978  exec "$SHELL"
 9979  pyenv versions
 9980  python -V
 9981  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

I've tried another command:  9986  export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
Then, I've went into nano ~/.zshrc. Here are some of it's contents:
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
 export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

 export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
  export ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"



plugins=(
  git
  zsh-syntax-highlighting
  zsh-autosuggestions
  pyenv
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh



# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

Now, whenever I open a terminal I get /home/george/.zshrc:12: command not found: pyenv
I am confused and have no idea what to do next.
I've read the following issues but I couldn't fix my problem:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/233
How to resolve .zshenv. command not found pyenv?
"pyenv versions" and "python -V" showing different versions


You are first callingpyenv, and later add $PYENV_ROOT/bin to your PATH. How is zsh supposed to find pyenv under this circumstances?

If you still get command not found, I guess that pyenv is in a different directory. Invoke it with an explicit full path then.

Does this answer your question? How do I get pyenv to display the executable path for an installed version?
